# UITableViewCells visible behind title when scrolling up in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

This is probably a simple fix, but I haven't been able to figure out what's going on.

I have a UITableView that looks like this:

[image]

When I scroll up, however, the cells are visible behind the title, like so:

[image]

I've tried changing the navigation bar to opaque in appDelegate:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
```

I have also tried editing the top insets on the UITableView without success. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have this code in a public git? It's hard to say what's going on because I can't see how you set your constraints. Is the navigationbar transculent?

Comment: It's a constraints issue, not an opacity issue. Can you update your question to show how/where you set up your constraints on the `UITableView`?

Comment: I was able to solve it by changing the properties of the navigation bar-- I know it was likely a constraints issue but this solved the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has the same problem, I just had to set the UINavigationBar tint color like so, and make it non-translucent:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = colorDict[currentClerkship]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: this means, that the barTintColor was transparent before?